# converting parts of json string with % into float during loading in python?

Tags: json, python-3.x

How do i load a json so that wherever % appears, preceding number (if any) changes to float.

*for example*:

```
json_string = '[5, "5.2%", {"value": "2%"}]' 

json.loads(json_string)
```

this gets decoded to `[5, "5.2%", {"value": "2%}]`

what is needed is `[5, 0.052, {"value": .02}]`

---

I am doing this currently as a post processing after a basic loading of json, but i would like json.loads to handle this for me. Appreciate any help

---

another solution i attempted but it looks clumsy:

```
class JsonXSimpleDecoder(json.JSONDecoder):
    # loads int as int, floats and pct as floats and date as datetime
    def decode(self, s):
        result = super().decode(s) 
        return self._decode(result)

    def _decode(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, str):
            result = o
            if "%" in o:
                new = o.replace("%", "")
                if is_number(new):
                    result = float(new) / 100
            elif "." in o and is_number(o):
                result = float(o)
            elif is_number(o):
                result = int(o)
            else:
                try:
                    dt = datetime.date.fromisoformat(o)
                    if isinstance(dt, datetime.date) and dt.isoformat() == o:
                        result = dt
                except ValueError:
                    pass
            return result
        elif isinstance(o, dict):
            return {k: self._decode(v) for k, v in o.items()}
        elif isinstance(o, list):
            return [self._decode(v) for v in o]
        else:
            return o
```

and then:

```
results = json.loads(json_string, cls=JsonXSimpleDecoder)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: The [``json`` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#encoders-and-decoders) describes how to influence loading of data. Did you try any of that? What problems did you encounter when implementing your own solution?

Comment: This is what i have attempted (adding in original question)

Answer (score 1):

Do a replacement on `json_string` beforehand. Regex works for this, as it's flexible enough to intelligently detect strings that contain numbers, and properly process them when replacing them with just straight numbers.

```
import re
import json

json_string = '[5, "5.2%", {"value": "2%"}]'

# Look for a number encased in double-quotes, with a percent sign at the end.
# Strip that match of the quotes and the percent sign (via string slicing),
# then convert it to a float, divide by 100, and convert it back to a string
# and finally, substitute it in for the original.
json_string = re.sub(r'"\d+\.?\d*%"', 
                     lambda m: str(float(m.group(0)[1:-2]) / 100), 
                     json_string)
# this produces '[5, 0.052000000000000005, {"value": 0.02}]'
# floating point precision is messy (search "is floating point math broken"),
# so this is as good as we're probably going to get.

# then, parse this as JSON, as normal
json_contents = json.loads(json_string)
# [5, 0.052000000000000005, {'value': 0.02}]
```

Comment: Would it not be easier to load the json as-is, then recursively search for a number followed by a "%", then replace it at that point? :)

Comment: that's what i was doing and i thought there may be a nicer solution. Hope someone has cleaner suggestion